# How To Work Around Apache Bind Port 80 Error

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, tomcat, windows-service

I believe my problem is related to the order in which windows services start. I have been searching this error before posting here. We are running Windows Server 2003. Both Apache (port 80) and IIS (port 8080) are running as well.

This server hosts two "legal" products produced by different companies. The product that runs on Apache also requires Tomcat. When the server has to be rebooted, this error is found in the system event log several times

```
Unable to bind to the underlying transport for 0.0.0.0:80. 
The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference to an interface 
which may not exist on this machine.  
The data field contains the error number.
```

and our clients' application won't let them log in.

After we restart the Apache service, everything is fine. That is Apache binds to port 80, and our clients can log into their application. Oh, and to make things interesting, SQL Server 2008 is installed on this system, and the reporting service is running.

If this were a port conflict, as many articles I researched suggest, restarting Apache should also fail. IIS and Apache are configured at different ports, and our manually restarting the apache service after rebooting fixes the problem.

I looked at the Apache service configuration, and it is dependent on TCP/IP starting first. Is there a way to delay apache starting or make it dependent on something that starts up later (after TCP/IP)?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the easyest way is to put a .bat file in startup that restarts the apache. Make sure the server logs on, because that when startup runs.